# Why is this different behavior?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Below, calling `things()` doesn't render anything. If I comment out `thing()`, and un-comment the code below it (that semantically is identical to the function `thing()`, just in place), I see the rows being displayed.

**Why is the behavior different?**

```
function things(){
    return (           
            <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button></td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.symbol}</td>                
                <td className={lastClass}>{this.props.stock.last}</td>
                <td className={changeClass}>{this.props.stock.change} <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.high}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.low}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
            </tr> 
            </tbody>                    
        );        
}

var StockRow = React.createClass({
    unwatch: function() {
        this.props.unwatchStockHandler(this.props.stock.symbol);
    },
    render: function () {
        var lastClass = '',
            changeClass = 'change-positive',
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top';
        if (this.props.stock === this.props.last) {
            lastClass = this.props.stock.change < 0 ? 'last-negative' : 'last-positive';
        }
        if (this.props.stock.change < 0) {
            changeClass = 'change-negative';
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom';
        }

        things(); //  this doesn't work. Uncomment below does work.Why?

        /*
        return (           
            <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button></td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.symbol}</td>                
                <td className={lastClass}>{this.props.stock.last}</td>
                <td className={changeClass}>{this.props.stock.change} <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.high}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.low}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
            </tr> 
            </tbody>                    
        );   
        */     
    }
});
```

Comment: return statement?

Comment: That's because when you call thing, the stuff is returned to render in StockRow but just sits there and does nothing. Do `return thing()`.

Comment: It's not semantically identical:`things()` doesn't return a value. This is expected behavior

Comment: return things(); doesn't work.

Comment: This will never work.. jsx is react specific and you're trying to return it from simple js function..

Comment: Additionally this in things() function points to global object, which in any case will not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put things function inside class and use it like this:
`return <div>{this.things()}</div>` it will work.

Check this working `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/455184rh/

Comment: Check the fiddle its working in ur case check the console error if it failing at any part it will log the error

Comment: There is already a containing table so your additional table in the example is incorrect. I need the code as shown to work.

Comment: Remove table tag in jsfiddle code it will work in that case also, i used that because I have to create a table.

Comment: I just said return ( this.things() );

Comment: I have no idea why it has to be inside a class. Node.js is strange if true. I am going to try to get it to work outside  a class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `things()` which will just throw data over there,  use return things() which will return data from class.

```
return (things());
```